# Rails: ajax form submission return new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm making a rails website. I have a remote form_for tag that creates a new issue through ajax call when I click the submit button. I want the rails app to add that new issue back to the browser javascript variable, the collection of issues.
Right now I have

```
----issues_controller.rb-----
def create
    @issue = @project.issues.new(issue_params)
    @issue.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @issue.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@project, @issue], notice: 'Issue was successfully created.' }
        format.js
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @issue }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @issue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

----create.js.erb----
var old_issues = $('#issues').data('issues');
old_issues += $.parseJSON(<%= @issue.to_json =>);
```

I've heard that if you are using to_json method then you are doing it wrong. What's the more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to add new data to the old data in the javascript. I got it now, apparently you don't need to parseJSON in the js side, also make sure to put raw before the @issue.to_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change this

```
old_issues += $.parseJSON(<%= @issue.to_json =>);
```

to this

```
old_issues = old_issues.concat(<%= raw @issue.to_json %>);
```

JS automatically converts json to object.